# Classification of multiobjective optimization algorithms

Tags: optimization, reference-request

I am looking for a good (canonical?) overview paper(s)/book(s) on the classification of multiobjective optimization algorithms. I am focused on obtaining a representative set of Pareto optimal solutions generally for real-world optimization problems in electromagnetics; however, the reference should not be field-restrictive.

The reference ideally should not focus only on evolutionary methods (this is the case of overview papers that I encountered), but probably compare the method families and give a broader overview.

Particular goals:

- have it as a to-go reference for the topic
- get the overview of major families and subfamilies of multiobjective optimization algorithms. In particular, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization#A_posteriori_methods) has

  > Most a posteriori methods fall into either one of the following two classes: **mathematical programming-based** a posteriori methods, where an algorithm is repeated and each run of the algorithm produces one Pareto optimal solution, and **evolutionary** algorithms where one run of the algorithm produces a set of Pareto optimal solutions.

  I wonder, what would be the methods (hybrid?) that does not fall in either of those classes.
- get it as a reference to use as a "justification" for choosing or not choosing evolutionary-based methods